# C++ pointers on example

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a sample code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  
  p2 = &secondvalue; 
  cout << "1.p1: " << p1 << ", p2: " << p2 << endl;
  cout << "1.*p1: " << *p1 << ", *p2: " << *p2 << endl;
  *p1 = 10;
  cout << "2.p1: " << p1 << ", p2: " << p2 << endl;
  cout << "2.*p1: " << *p1 << ", *p2: " << *p2 << endl;
  *p2 = *p1; 
  cout << "3.p1: " << p1 << ", p2: " << p2 << endl;
  cout << "3.*p1: " << *p1 << ", *p2: " << *p2 << endl;
  p1 = p2;
  cout << "4.p1: " << p1 << ", p2: " << p2 << endl;
  cout << "4.*p1: " << *p1 << ", *p2: " << *p2 << endl;
  *p1 = 20;          
  cout << "5.p1: " << p1 << ", p2: " << p2 << endl;
  cout << "5.*p1: " << *p1 << ", *p2: " << *p2 << endl;  
  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << endl;
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << endl;
  cout << "firstvalue is " << &firstvalue << endl;
  cout << "secondvalue is " << &secondvalue << endl;

  getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output :

```
1.p1: 0041FB40, p2: 0041FB34
1.*p1: 5, *p2: 15
2.p1: 0041FB40, p2: 0041FB34
2.*p1: 10, *p2: 15
3.p1: 0041FB40, p2: 0041FB34
3.*p1: 10, *p2: 10
4.p1: 0041FB34, p2: 0041FB34
4.*p1: 10, *p2: 10
5.p1: 0041FB34, p2: 0041FB34
5.*p1: 20, *p2: 20
firstvalue is 10
secondvalue is 20
firstvalue is 0041FB40
secondvalue is 0041FB34
```

What is copied in the line "p1 = p2" ? Does p1 become reference to p2 or does it work in different way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just say: *"Now `p1` should point at the same memory block as `p2` does".*

So they start pointing at the same memory block (to the same *address*) and, hence, share the same values.

Answer (score 1):

memory address
p1 takes on the memory address of p2 (0041FB34)

Comment: apart from the use of 'cout' and '<<', your sample is plain C.  and C, almost by definition, doesn't to magic.

Answer (score 1):

Since `p2` contains the address of `secondvalue`, `p1=p2;` copies the address of `secondvalue` from `p2` into `p1`. I'd advise against calling it a reference if you can help it though -- a reference is something else that's similar enough to a pointer to cause confusion anyway, so calling a pointer a reference (or even thinking of it as a reference) is probably a poor idea.

Answer (score 0):

After the assignment, `p1` will contain the same memory address as `p2`. The two pointers will point to the same variable, so `*p1` and `*p2` refer to the same memory.

Aside of that there is no special connection between `p1` and `p2`. For example a following assignment like `p1 = &firstvalue` will not change anything about the `p2` pointer variable and `p1` and `p2` will point to different memory locations again.

Answer (score 0):

= (the assignment operator) just copies the values of one variable (p2) into another (p1). So, after the assignment, p1 and p2 are synonymous in that they reference the same address -- dereferencing them will give the same value, as seen in your printout.

For more information, try this [article](http://www.linuxconfig.org/c-understanding-pointers) on pointers.